# Out of Range Error on Monitor (win7)

Tags: windows, hard-drive, display, graphics-card, sata

We've got two PCs with different motherboards, graphic cards, HDDs, etc.

- *PC1: HDD1: Maxtor - SATA - 240 GB - Win XP - Partition Drives C,D,E*
- *PC2: HDD2: Samsung - SATA - 500 GB - Win 7 - Partition Drives C,D,E,F*

Both HDDs have been bought almost 5 years ago.

Now I want to have the both hard drives in PC1.

I mounted and screwed the HDD2 on PC1 and plugged its SATA and power cables. When I booted the system, I entered the BIOS settings and set the first booting priority to HDD2 (win 7).

***The Problem:***

When I power on my PC, it starts to load the win 7, and the progress bar appears. But instead of showing the welcome screen, the following error appears:

> Out of Range
>
> 63.7 khz / 60 hz

and nothing else comes. This error remains on the screen forever!

I searched a lot for this error on the internet. Almost all of them say that this error is because of the ***screen resolution*** and the ***refresh rate***. They suggest to load the system in safe mode with lower resolution (640x480) so as to be able to change its resolution settings in safe mode.

But the problem is that when I enter the safe mode with lower resolution, the welcome screen appears, but again that "Out of Range" error comes!

I know that this error is probably because of different graphic cards, different display adapters, and different resolution settings. But when I can't enter even the safe mode, how can I disable/uninstall/change these settings?

What should I do now?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let me get this straight: You're trying to boot from a HDD that comes from a PC with completely different hardware?

Comment: Thanks @Sharain for your comment. Actually, yes. The second HDD comes from another PC with different hardware. But it's not completely different! Since they were both bought almost 5 years ago, hardware specifications are almost the same, with some minor differences.

Comment: Even minor differences can be enough, as it's a matter of driver compatibility. But booting a PC in safemode SHOULD in theory only load core drivers. Does the PC user the built-in graphics card, or an "external" one? If so, try to put the monitor on the built-in port (or really, any other port that can work), to see if you get a proper image.

Comment: Thanks again @Sharain for your comment. Both PCs use external graphic cards. The PC2 uses Nvidia GeForce 9500 GT, and the PC1 uses Nvidia GeForce 9400 GT. Unfortunately, booting in safe mode with lower resolution doesn't help, and the same error comes (though after welcome screen).

Comment: Ok, then remove the monitor from the graphics card, and instead plug it into the built-in one, if there is one.

Comment: My motherboard is Gigabyte GA-EP43-DS3L @Sharain , and unfortunately, it doesn't have on-board graphics. Any other suggestions?